# Beta and gamma function problem

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

> Show that $$\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx \times \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}$$

I'm trying to solve this problem but I can't prove it. In the end, I got $\Gamma(3/8)$, and $\Gamma(5/8)$ but I don't know how to solve their values.

Firstly I put $x^2=\sin(\theta)$ and solve the first part and $x^2=\tan(\theta)$. I don't know whether to combine both functions or solve them separately.I tried both but was not able to solve them. Please help guys

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\Gamma(\frac38)$ and $\Gamma(\frac58)$ do not have simpler forms.  However, their product does.  (Euler's reflection formula)

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, let $x^2=\sin \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{4} B\left(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
For the second, let $x^2=\tan \theta$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sec \theta} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\tan \theta}} \sec ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin \theta \cos \theta}} d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2 \theta}} d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta d \theta\\&=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} B\left(\frac{1}{4} ,\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Multiplying them yields$$
\begin{aligned}
I \times J= & \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 \sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{16 \sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{16 \sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\frac{1}{4} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$